# NoSuchElement exception when selecting an option using selectByVisibleText

Tags: java, selenium

I had done this for all select in my project and everything is working fine except this  select [image: select] .

I am selecting the option "PIT - (111310001)" using  `selectByVisibleText` and problem is, this method doesn't take any regex or substring so that i can remove the other character from the "*PIT - (111310001)*" option.

Any help why it is not working ??

Edit :-

I am doing this now for selecting that option.

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id(Fieldname)))
.selectByVisibleText(Value.trim());
for (WebElement option : options) {
   if(option.getText().contains(Value.trim()))
   {
    System.out.println(option);
    option.click();
    break;
   }
}
```

I don't want to use selectByIndex or selectByValue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`selectByVisibleText` is checking for exact match, including white spaces before and after the string (which you remove with `trim()`). I suggest you copy the text from the html to make sure.

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id(Fieldname))).selectByVisibleText(Value);
```

Another way to make sure the text is accurate

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//option[contains(text(), 'PIT')]")).getText(); // find the option by partial text and take the full text
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id(Fieldname))).selectByVisibleText(text);
```